# Show running application more useful (alt-tab)

Tags: 14.04

I'm using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to move focusing between windows, but when there are many applications running, it shows as scroll and I have difficulties to choose by mouse.

Is there any way to modify the view of <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on ubuntu to show the running app in table view example (may be show it in 2 or 3 lines)?

==== EDIT =====

Current view:

[image]

My expectation, so I can switch it easier:

[[image: My expectation like that]

Comment: After reading your question I just tested and it seems different under `4.4.0-53-generic` update. I like it better. Are you running the same version? Use 'uname -r` to find out.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this version `4.4.0-53-generic`, but ` I like it better.` mean? do you like to show as scrolling?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: @QuanVo I think I get your point... the arrow keys don't work when it drills down to sub-windows, you have to click with your mouse right?

Comment: @PyGeek03 & WinEunuuchs2Unix, could you recheck my updated.

Comment: Please checkout the first post in this link: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211863 (I cannot test if this would work because I don't use Unity, sorry :P) If it doesn't work, you can try changing to Gnome desktop.

Comment: **Static Application Switcher** which work as my expectation, thanks for helping @PyGeek03.

Comment: consider using Window Spread mode. That's Win key + W.